# Why can't I call out the UIAlert function by using guard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

The alert function is not called but there are no errors

```
@objc func handleSignUp(){

   guard let email = emailTextField.text else {
        let alertemail = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Please enter a valid email address!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let actionemail = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (actionemail) in
            alertemail.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertemail.addAction(actionemail)
        self.present(alertemail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else {
        let alertpassword = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Please enter a valid password!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let actionpassword = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (actionpassword) in
            alertpassword.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        alertpassword.addAction(actionpassword)
        return
    }

    createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
}
```

Comment: What happens after you return from handleSignUp. share the code that calls this method.

Comment: button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignUp), for: .touchUpInside) //this is the code that I calls this method.

Answer (score 0):

The `text` property of an `UITextField` object (unlike `UILabel`) is never `nil`. [*This string is @"" by default*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text).

You could add a check if the string is empty

```
guard let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty else { ...
```

However you should validate the email address